# Is there a reason why custom field sets cannot be multiple value?

Tags: forms, civicrm-entity

I've added a custom field set to the Participant entity, but I need to it allow for multiple values. I've noticed that the Contact entity has no problem with this, but is there a reason why it doesn't give you this option for other entities?

I've found the cause in this function in the `templates/CRM/Custom/Form/Group.tpl` file:

```
  /**
   * Check if this is a contact-related set and show/hide other options accordingly
   */
  function showHideStyle() {
    var
      extend = $(this).val(),
      contactTypes = {/literal}{$contactTypes}{literal},
      showStyle = "{/literal}{$showStyle}{literal}",
      showMultiple = "{/literal}{$showMultiple}{literal}",
      showMaxMultiple = "{/literal}{$showMaxMultiple}{literal}",
      isContact = ($.inArray(extend, contactTypes) >= 0);

    if (isContact) {
      $("tr#style_row, tr#is_multiple_row").show();
      if ($('#is_multiple :checked').length) {
        $("tr#multiple_row").show();
      }
    }
    else {
      $("tr#style_row, tr#is_multiple_row, tr#multiple_row").hide();
    }

    if (showStyle) {
      $("tr#style_row").show();
    }

    if (showMultiple) {
      $("tr#style_row, tr#is_multiple_row").show();
    }

    if (!showMaxMultiple) {
      $("tr#multiple_row").hide();
    }
    else if ($('#is_multiple').prop('checked')) {
      $("tr#multiple_row").show();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It would be useful to elaborate on the use case - what are the multiple values, for what kinds of fields?

Comment: I need participants to be able to add multiple files. Each of which have titles, descriptions and other fields.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says they are only possible for contact records. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/#multiple-record-fieldsets. I expect the reason for this is that it would have been a lot more effort to add it for all for other entities. There are some built in ones for contacts so I guess it was easier to extend for contacts. It wasn't there from the start

Comment: I forgot to reply here, thanks for the explanation! I've done a little investigating and done some work and got something to work. I've posted it as answer! I hope to revisit it and see if I can make a patch for it to work on all entities (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to get the Participant entity to accept multiple values.

To recap, I needed a custom field set that contained single value text, note and file fields, but needed to be able to add multiple instances of the set itself to a Participant.

I added the following code to the top of the`CRM_Event_Form_Participant::postProcess` method, underneath the line     `$params = $this->controller->exportValues($this->_name);`.

```
// Get CiviCRM's configuration
$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
$uploadDirectory = $config->uploadDir;

// Filter keys that are in the form of custom_[number]_-[number over 1]
$custom_field_keys = preg_grep('/custom_[0-9]+_-[2-9]+/', array_keys($this->_submitValues));
foreach ($custom_field_keys as $key) {

  // Save these additional values in the $params array
  $params[$key] = $this->_submitValues[$key];
}

// Filter out keys that are in the form of custom_[number]_-[number over 1]
$custom_file_keys = preg_grep('/custom_[0-9]+_-[2-9]+/', array_keys($this->_submitFiles));

foreach ($custom_file_keys as $key) {

  // rename the uploaded file with a unique number at the end
  $file = $this->_submitFiles[$key];

  $element = new HTML_QuickForm_file($key);
  $element->_value = $file;

  $newName = CRM_Utils_File::makeFileName($file['name']);
  $status = $element->moveUploadedFile($uploadDirectory, $newName);
  if (!$status) {
    CRM_Core_Error::statusBounce(ts('We could not move the uploaded file %1 to the upload directory %2. Please verify that the \'Temporary Files\' setting points to a valid path which is writable by your web server.', [
      1 => $value['name'],
      2 => $uploadDirectory,
    ]));
  }
  if (!empty($data['values'][$pageName][$uploadName]['name'])) {
    @unlink($uploadDirectory . $data['values'][$pageName][$uploadName]);
  }

  $value = [
    'name' => $uploadDirectory . $newName,
    'type' => $element->_value['type'],
  ];
  //CRM-19460 handle brackets if present in $uploadName, similar things we do it for all other inputs.
  $value = $element->_prepareValue($value, TRUE);
  $params = HTML_QuickForm::arrayMerge($params, $value);
}
```

It begins by first getting the upload directory path from configuration and then finding all keys in the `_submitValues` property that are the second value onwards. Adding these values directly to the `$params` array appears to work with no additional work.

For files, the same beginning is needed where we find file field keys that are the second onwards, then we must create a new file field instance with `HTML_QuickForm_file` for each one, so we may utilise the `HTML_QuickForm_file::moveUploadedFile()` method. If the file is moved successfully, we prepare the new file values and merge them into the `$params` array.

Comment: is this a potential patch for core or released as an extension so others can benefit from your work

Comment: It could potentially be a patch, I think I've identified to point where multiple value field sets fail though, which I'd like to share and work on. Ultimately, it's because when you add a new instance of a custom field set on the form, it just returns the markup to do so, it doesn't actually add it to the _elements or _elementsIndex array properties of the form. I think if this happened, it might just work. The contact entity works, so I might start there.